# Why is action delayed?

Tags: akka, gatling

I use Gatling simulation that combines http requests with simple custom actions. I am seeing a problem that occasionally there's a long (60 seconds) delay between two consecutive actions that should be executed immediatelly:

```
.exec(s => {
    System.out.printf(/* logging time here */);
    s
  })
.exec(/* my custom action */)
```

and I log timestamp in `Chainable.execute()` in my custom action. This mostly works, but some executions get delayed for no obvious reason (and the custom action fails since it must be done in less than a minute after the preceding actions).

Since I am new to actors, is there any way to debug where is the message to continue with next action hanging? I thought that the follow up action should be executed right away in the same thread (since nothing should block that), but that does not seem to be true.

The system is not stuck during the delay; other actions are executed in the meantime, and the CPU is not fully utilized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smells like blocking code, check your threads. And no, you have no guarantee that the same thread is used for consecutive actions.

If you have a blocking call in your Action implementation, you're actually blocking one of the Akka threads, so you end up with a thread starvation and your workflow can now longer proceed until some threads become available again.

DO NOT BLOCK IN THERE. If you're using a blocking API (which is wrong anyway), delegate to a dedicated thread pool.

Comment: The action uses blocking code (calls to external API), but only after the mentioned log. Is it possible that the action is not executed since another instances of the action are executing?

Comment: Yep, that helped. I thought that when I see enough unoccupied akka threads, it should work, but apparently it's more complicated.